# Getting error that Firebase isn't configured even though I have configured it

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I get an error that I need to add FirebaseApp.configure() to the app delegate, but I've already configured it.

I've ran the code successfully in the past, this error just began occurring. Based on previous questions about this I've tried:

- running pod update in terminal
- re-downloading and re-adding the GoogleService-Info.plist file

Does anyone know what's going on?

Here's the specific error: The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) to your application initialization. Read more: ...

EDIT:

Have also tried:

- cleaning the build folder
- Deleting the app's folder in DerivedData

EDIT #2: Here is my AppDelegate file

[image: AppDelegate file]

Comment: Did you try to purge, update and install your pods?
Also, did you try to run the xCode again resetting all cache?

Comment: I tried to update and reinstall pods. How do you reset Xcode's cache?

Comment: In Xcode, set the emulator/device target then press CMD + SHIFT + R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the issue was that I had put an instance of Auth.auth() before viewDidLoad, causing the error. Everything works now.

Edit: Here's the difference in code:

Here's the code that threw an error

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let ref = Database.database().reference() // Caused error
    var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var locationData = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}
```

Here's the corrected code, where ref is set in viewDidLoad

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var ref: DatabaseReference?
    var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var locationData = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setFirebase()
    }

    func setFirebase() {
        ref = Database.database().reference()
    }
}
```

Comment: Try putting some code that shows your before (not working) and after (working) to help others who may come across this in the future.